# Non-Research Transportation Raster applications

Tags: raster, imagery, transportation

My experience with rasters is pretty basic. 99.95% of what I do involves vector and transportation modelling. In research, there are numerous transportation applications using rasters and imagery however, these applications although realistic and great, seem to me as a bad representation of the state of practice of Transportation and rasters/imagery.

What is the state of the practice on using imagery and raster analysis in transportation?

Comment: Would this include systems that use an array of license plate recognition cameras to track vehicles as they drive through a neighborhood?

Comment: sure, Like an OCR reader for license plate cameras on tolls or weigh-in-motion systems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Cost Surface and least cost path analysis is one possibility for transportation:

http://www.spatialanalysisonline.com/output/html/Accumulatedcostsurfacesandleastcostpaths.html